# Greatest Common Divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have calculated $d = 39$ but don't know how to find $u$ and $v$.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e22ea5d108cc3bfb7a09870e6fbb5177.png?1366382429))</sub>

Btw I know this is not really a cryptography question, but there isn't a tag for GCD.

Comment: Is it me or does $6$ not divide $975$?

Comment: @Lord_Farin Yes you're right. I must have made a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\GCD}{\operatorname{GCD}}$

**Hint:**

Use *extended* Euclid's division Algorithm as vonbrand suggested.

$ax+by=\GCD(a,b)$

---

$2184=975 \times 2+234$

$975=234 \times 3+39$

$234=39 \times 6+0$

$\GCD (2184,975)=39$

Now use the method of back-substitution:

$\ 975-(234  \times 3)=39 $

$\ 975-((2184-(975 \times 2))  \times 3)=39 $

Comment: Use the _extended_ Euclidean algorithm

Comment: Well, yes! Extended one.

Comment: ...about which you may read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: @Inceptio Can you show the workings for the second part, please. I don't understand the Wikipedia method.

Comment: Did you see the **edited** version?

Comment: I already have the solution to that. I got 39 as well. I'm talking about solving for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't see the **substitution** part. $39=975-234 \times 3 $

$234=2184-975 \times 2$. Substitute $2184-975 \times 2$ instead of $234$ back in there.

You get everything in terms of $2184$ and $975$.

Comment: @Inceptio So that gives me **39 = 975 - (2184 - 975 x 2) x 4**. Right? So how do I then get $v$ and $u$?

Comment: What are the coefficients of $2184$ and $97$. They are $u$ and $v$ respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a matrix technique. First, write

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & 0 & 2184 \\ 0 & 1 & 975 \end{array}\right]$$

Then perform repeated row operations, e.g.:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & 0 & 2184 \\ 0 & 1 & 975 \end{array}\right] \stackrel{R_1-2R_2}{\longrightarrow} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & -2 & 234 \\ 0 & 1 & 975 \end{array}\right] \stackrel{R_2-4R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & -2 & 234 \\ -4 & 9 & 39 \end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & -2 & 234 \\ -4 & 9 & 39 \end{array}\right] \stackrel{R_2-4R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}
 1 & -2 & 234 \\ -4 & 9 & 39 \end{array}\right]$$

Since $39$ divides $234$ we stop and we get $\gcd(2184,975) = 39$ and, $(-4) \cdot 2184 + 9 \cdot 975 = 39$.

Comment: This is nice(+1)

Comment: What operations are you doing in between the matrices?

Comment: Row operations.

Comment: @FlybyNight I know. I meant what arithmetic operations?

Comment: For example, $R_1-3R_2$ means subtract three lots of row two from row one. You subtract term by term. Because 975 goes into 2184 twice, leaving a remainder, I do $R_1-2R_2$. Then because 234 goes into 975 four times, leaving a remainder, I do $R_2-4R_1$. You keep juggling like this, taking as many lots of the smaller from the bigger until the smaller divides into the bigger without remainder.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling the gcd: $\rm\ 56u + 25v = 1\:\Rightarrow\: mod\ 25\!:\ u \equiv \dfrac{1}{56}\equiv \dfrac{-24}6 \ \equiv -4,\ $ so $\rm\ u = -4\! +\! 25n,\: $ so $\rm\: v = (1\!-\!56u)/25\, =\, (1-56(-4\!+\!25n))/25\, =\, 9\!-\!56n,\: $ i.e. $\rm\: (u,v)\, =\, (-4,9)+(25,-26)n$.

**Remark** $\ $ Generally it is more efficient to employ the [*extended* Euclidean algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500)

Answer (score 0):

**By using *The Extended Euclidean Algorithm***

$gcd(2184, 975) = x$

$2184 = 2*975 + 234$

$975 = 4*234 + 39$

$234 = 6*39$

Thus $gcd(2184, 975) = 39$

$d = 2184u + 975v$. Solve for $u$ and $v$.

$39 = 975 - 4*234$

$39 = 975 - 4(2184 - 2*975)$

$39 = 9*975 - 4*2184$

$u = -4$ and $v = 9$

[Two more examples here.](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~math418/m418oh/m418oh04.pdf)